Error when building code using ncurses with Bazel: conflicting types for 'unctrl'
I have a project built with Bazel that uses ncurses. I am trying to migrate to bzlmod for Bazel 8.0.0 LTS. Previously, I was using a local repository, which was working fine. Now, I am trying to use the ncurses module from the Bazel Central Repository.
I have this minimal repro case for this here: https://github.com/davidzchen/bazel-ncurses-example
I am getting an odd compilation error about conflicting types for 'unctrl'. Here is the error that I am getting:
$ bazel build //foo:color --verbose_failures
INFO: Analyzed target //foo:color (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
ERROR: /Users/dzc/Projects/davidzchen/bazel-ncurses-example/foo/BUILD:3:11: Compiling foo/color.cc failed: (Exit 1): cc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target //foo:color)
  (cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_dzc/87450ce08cbc0c792b19d6253d30d152/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/143/execroot/_main && \
  exec env - \
    PATH='/Users/dzc/Library/Caches/bazelisk/downloads/sha256/ea529c3c03d6981e13e25af126b63b41435c9a42bf28435bbabbe3b11542ddcf/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/dzc/.bin:/Users/dzc/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/utilities:/Users/dzc/go/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands:/Users/dzc/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/lib:/Users/dzc/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/history-substring-search:/Users/dzc/.antigen/bundles/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting:/Users/dzc/.antigen/bundles/zsh-users/zsh-completions:/Users/dzc/.antigen/bundles/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions' \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  external/rules_cc++cc_configure_extension+local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fcolor-diagnostics -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++17' '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/foo/_objs/color/color.o' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin -iquote external/ncurses+ -iquote bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/external/ncurses+ -isystem external/ncurses+/include -isystem bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/external/ncurses+/include -isystem external/ncurses+/ncurses -isystem bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/external/ncurses+/ncurses '-mmacosx-version-min=15.2' -MD -MF bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/foo/_objs/color/color.d '-std=c++20' -c foo/color.cc -o bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/foo/_objs/color/color.o -no-canonical-prefixes -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -Xclang '-fmodule-name=//foo:color' -Xclang '-fmodule-map-file=bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/foo/color.cppmap' -Xclang -fno-cxx-modules -fmodules-strict-decluse -Wprivate-header -Xclang '-fmodule-map-file=external/rules_cc++cc_configure_extension+local_config_cc/module.modulemap' -Xclang '-fmodule-map-file=bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/external/ncurses+/ncurses.cppmap')
# Configuration: 9b382b18c38178c86436d40b630070f6a7b54b2d54b8541e3a8dda9e825538d4
# Execution platform: @@platforms//host:host

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
In file included from foo/color.cc:3:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ncurses.h:2918:
bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/external/ncurses+/include/unctrl.h:61:54: error: conflicting types for 'unctrl'
   61 | NCURSES_EXPORT(NCURSES_CONST char *) NCURSES_SP_NAME(unctrl) (SCREEN*, chtype);
      |                                                      ^
bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/external/ncurses+/include/unctrl.h:58:38: note: previous declaration is here
   58 | NCURSES_EXPORT(NCURSES_CONST char *) unctrl (chtype);
      |                                      ^
1 error generated.
Target //foo:color failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.201s, Critical Path: 0.91s
INFO: 97 processes: 11 internal, 86 darwin-sandbox.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully

Interestingly, bazel build @ncurses succeeds.
What is odd to me is that Bazel is finding the ncurses.h from the system rather than from the remote archive.
I also tried adding common --incompatible_strict_action_env to my .bazelrc, but I still get the same error.
Does anyone know what is causing this issue and how to resolve it?
I’m using Bazel 8.0.0 and am on macOS Sequoia 15.2

Here, too, the relevant code needs to be included here, not on some external site.

I think it is easier to link the repo because the relevant code comprises multiple files, and linking the repo allows people to try to build the code themselves. Is there a rule on this site that all relevant code must be inline?
